# Reload a JS radioplayer in HTML file with new JS values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

HTML:

```html
<div id="flashradiobig"></div>
```

JavaScript radio player (jQuery):

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#flashradiobig").flashradio({
    streamurl: "http://5.135.83.159", 
    streamtype: "shoutcast2", 
});
</script>
```

I would like to click on an image, which will reload my `div` including the radioplayer with new values for "streamurl" and "streamtype".

I tried to reload the `div` including the player by doing this `load` below. But, the player keeps the same parameters... stream url and stream type are unchanged.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".radio-preview").on('click',function(event) {
      var url = $(this).prop('href');
      $("#flashradiobig").load(url);
      event.preventDefault();
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: wrap init in a function then onclick run function again.

Answer (score 0):

## Use Global data-*

You can use html global data-* on every image as an attribute for streamurl and streamtype.
Here is an example:

HTML:

`<img src="[URL]" data-stream-url="http://5.135.83.159" data-stream-type="shoutcast2"/>`

`<img src="[URL]" data-stream-url="http://urltoradio" data-stream-type="shoutcast1"/>`

More: [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp).

## Solution

Here is the solution of your question using jQuery on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/carlocorradini/pen/PQXwzZ).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I Hope _FlashRadio_ will add a function to change the different options without recreating it every time.

Comment: Thank you very much. This was exactly what i was looking for. But I still have some issues to reload my div (including the player) with the new parameters (stream url and stream type).

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't. You are using an external library that has a specific and _unknown_ internal system. To change it without recreating it you have to '_wait_' the owner to create a specific function that is not present now. An example(only JavaScript has been changed): [CodePen](https://codepen.io/carlocorradini/pen/GQPjqg).